# Waiting until the google map has size in a MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

My activity contains a MapFragment in a LinearLayout. I do the following

in onCreate:

- I inflate this layout using setContentView in the onCreate method of
  my activity.
- Get a handle to the `GoogleMap` using `getMap()`.

in onStart:

- I get some place coordinates from an SQLite Database
- add corresponding markers to the map
- add these points to a `LatLngBounds.Builder`
- animate the camera using `newLatLngBounds(Builder.build(), 10)`

According to maps api reference, I shouldn't call `newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds bounds, int padding)` before making sure that the map has a size. I indeed get an IllegalStateException at this point. But what is the right method for **waiting until the map has a size**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have succesfully used the following code in the past:

```
final LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
final View mapView = fragment.getView();
final GoogleMap map = fragment.getMap():

//Add points to builder. And get bounds...
final LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

// Pan to see all markers in view.
// Cannot zoom to bounds until the map has a size.

if (mapView.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {
    mapView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50), 1500, null);         
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So was I :-) I have added the code to get the map view from the fragment.

Comment: from API level 16 `removeGlobalOnLayoutListener` spells `removeOnGlobalLayoutListener` (the first one has been deprecated)

Answer (score 11):

The [solution by rusmus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21383794/1121497) didn't work for me. I used this one instead:

```
    map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {
            map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }
    });
```

If you know the map size, you can avoid waiting and move the camera before the map is displayed. We finally used the display size as an approximation of the map size (but you could find out the exact size if you want to be more precise):

```
    final DisplayMetrics display = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    final int padding = display.widthPixels / 20;
    final CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(
        boundsBuilder.build(), display.widthPixels, display.heightPixels, padding);
    map.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

Comment: This answer does something slightly different than the one by rusmus.  `OnGlobalLayoutListener()` gets called when the map view is laid out, while `OnMapLoadedCallback()` gets called when all the map tiles are loaded, which is after the map view is laid out.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I was using onMapReady callback, but this one actually does the trick

Answer (score 1):

With the latest GoogleServices you can use [MapFragment.getMapAsync](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)).
Directly from the docs

> Sets a callback object which will be triggered when the GoogleMap instance is ready to be used.

Comment: Yes, by implementing the OnMapReadyCallback interface, and its onMapReady callback method. Unfortunately, when the callback is called, the map can be used, but map size may still be zero.